# Fetch keys which are older than 10 days from redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, redis-cli

I am trying to fetch the keys from Redis which are older than 10 days. I am using Zrange to fetch the old keys which are saved based on timestamp. I am getting this error when I run the last command **ERR value is not an integer or out of range**.Any help is appreciated or can someone guide me if I am doing wrong way

These are the values/timestamp I have used while adding in redis

```
Time.current.to_i => 1676960645
(Time.current - 3.days).to_i => 1676701452
(Time.current - 13.days).to_i => 1675837471
(Time.current - 10.days).to_i => 1676096682

redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1676960645 "current"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1676701452 "3 days ago"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1675837471 "13 days ago"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset )1676096682 1676960645
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Version:

redis-cli -v
redis-cli 4.0.9

As per Guy Royse comments, I have updated the Redis to 7.0.8 and I still getting the same error

```
redis-server --version
Redis server v=7.0.8 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.2.1 bits=64 build=c255d0976966edae
aniket@Linuxbeta:~$ redis-cli --version
redis-cli 7.0.8




    127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1676960645 "current"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1676701452 "3 days ago"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myzset 1675837471 "13 days ago"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset (1676096682 1676960645 BYSCORE
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Sorted Set ranges are specified using the index of the members. The lowest score is 0, the next lowest is 1, etc. In this scenario, exclusion is neither needed nor permitted. To execute exclusively, you just use the index you actually want.

What you are doing is asking for a range based on the *score*. With exclusivity. There are two problems with how this is being done:

1. You need to tell Redis that you are not looking for a range by index but instead by score. You do this using the BYSCORE option on [ZRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrange/).
2. You need to use a left parenthesis to specify exclusion, not a right one.

The command you want is:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset (1676096682 1676960645 BYSCORE
1) "3 days ago"
2) "current"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually getting this error 127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset (1676096682 1676960645 BYSCORE
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range

Comment: What version of Redis are you using? You might need to call ZRANGEBYSCORE if it's older than 6.2.

Comment: I see that you provided the version for redis-cli as 4.0.9 but the cli and Redis itself are different things.

Comment: redis-server --version
Redis server v=4.0.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=9435c3c2879311f3

Comment: redis-cli and redis-server both are same version 4.0.9

Comment: After upgrading the redis-cli and redis server to 7.0.8. I am still getting the same error  ZRANGE myzset (1676096682 1676960645 BYSCORE
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range

Comment: I have updated the same in the question

Comment: After restarting the redis-server I am now getting the following response but I need this result "13 days ago" instead of the above two

Comment: I think I got the solution ZRANGE myzset -inf (1676096682  BYSCORE to fetch the values older than 10 days

Comment: Glad ya got it working!